# How can I tell whether I installed Homebrew correctly?

Tags: macos, homebrew

A while ago, I installed Homebrew on my Mac and I'm worried I did it incorrectly and it's causing Brew not to work correctly. Is there some kind of command I can run from terminal to check if everything is working correctly?

There are two reasons I'm worried that it's not set up correctly:

1. I'm watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SELYgZvAZbU) in which he runs the command `brew search` and it gives him a list of packages he can install. But when I run the command I get the error message `This command requires at least 1 text or regex argument.` Is this normal?
2. When I run brew commands, it takes much longer than when I run other commands from terminal (maybe 3 seconds). Is this normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`brew --version` would be basic and easiest way to check if the software got installed successfully.

```sh
$ brew --version
Homebrew 3.2.17-108-ge518ea4
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 4eaec4244d4; last commit 2021-10-21)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 4d10ee7007; last commit 2021-10-22)
```

And for `brew` command, you can run help to understand further options you can try on, like this

```sh
$ brew search --help
Usage: brew search, -S [options] text|/regex/ [...]

Perform a substring search of cask tokens and formula names for text. If
text is flanked by slashes, it is interpreted as a regular expression. The
search for text is extended online to homebrew/core and homebrew/cask.

      --formula, --formulae        Search online and locally for formulae.
      --cask, --casks              Search online and locally for casks.
      --desc                       Search for formulae with a description
                                   matching text and casks with a name
                                   matching text.
      --pull-request               Search for GitHub pull requests containing
                                   text.
      --open                       Search for only open GitHub pull requests.
      --closed                     Search for only closed GitHub pull
                                   requests.
      --repology                   Search for text in the given database.
      --macports                   Search for text in the given database.
      --fink                       Search for text in the given database.
      --opensuse                   Search for text in the given database.
      --fedora                     Search for text in the given database.
      --archlinux                  Search for text in the given database.
      --debian                     Search for text in the given database.
      --ubuntu                     Search for text in the given database.
  -d, --debug                      Display any debugging information.
  -q, --quiet                      Make some output more quiet.
  -v, --verbose                    Make some output more verbose.
  -h, --help                       Show this message.
```

For example, if I want to install `go`, I can do `brew search go`:

```
$ brew search node
==> Formulae
heroku/brew/heroku-node ✔            node ✔                               node@10                              node_exporter                        nodenv
libbitcoin-node                      node-build                           node@12                              nodebrew                             ode
llnode                               node-sass                            node@14                              nodeenv
==> Casks
font-ubuntu-mono-derivative-powerline                         nodebox                                                       nodeclipse
nodebox                                                       nodeclipse

If you meant "node" specifically:
It was migrated from homebrew/cask to homebrew/core.
```

Comment: `brew doctor` also provides a good check-up of your installation.